# C# How do I pass more than just IAsyncResult into AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, iasyncresult, asynccallback

How do I pass more than just the IAsyncResult into AsyncCallback?

Example code:

```
//Usage
var req = (HttpWebRequest)iAreq;
req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(iEndGetResponse), req);

//Method
private void iEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult iA, bool iWantInToo) { /*...*/ }
```

I would like to pass in example variable `bool iWantInToo`. I don't know how to add that to `new AsyncCallback(iEndGetResponse)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use the object state to pass it in.  Right now, you're passing in the `req` parameter - but you can, instead, pass in an object containing both it and the boolean value.

For example (using .NET 4's Tuple - if you're in .NET <=3.5, you can use a custom class or KeyValuePair, or similar):

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)iAreq;
bool iWantInToo = true;
req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(iEndGetResponse), Tuple.Create(req, iWantInToo));

//Method
private void iEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult iA) 
{
    Tuple<HttpWebRequest, bool> state = (Tuple<HttpWebRequest, bool>)iA.AsyncState;
    bool iWantInToo = state.Item2;

    // use values..
}
```

Comment: Very very interesting. Testing this now. I've never seen this Tuple deal before, looks very useful!

Comment: Nobody sees this method ugly? There is supposed to be a better to pass parameters.

Comment: @derek this pattern, in general, has been replaced for async work.  most newer apis work against Task <T>

Comment: @ReedCopsey So modern way is to use "await" to let the callback finish and then do the job what previously "callback" did?

Comment: @derek Yes.  `await` makes callbacks unnecessary